# ¿Cómo se empieza a calcular el número de eventos diarios a partir de una tabla que sólo almacena el número total de eventos?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, etl

Quiero crear una tabla con el número de comparticiones por tipo de acción para cada día. Tengo una tabla que me dice cuántas comparticiones ha tenido una determinada comunidad:

```
CREATE TABLE communities
    (`community_id` int, `shares_copylink` int, `shares_email` int, `shares_facebook` int, `shares_messenger` int, `shares_pinterest` int, `shares_twitter` int, `shares_whatsapp` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO communities
    (`community_id`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (2, 2, 2, 196, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (3, 8, 20, 0, 8, 0, 0, 12),
    (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (7, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (8, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (12, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
    (14, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3),
    (16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (62, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 9),
    (65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (79, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (104, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4),
    (105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (109, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (145, 0, 1, 39, 1, 0, 0, 4),
    (146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (148, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
;
```

No se puede obtener esta información de forma retroactiva, ya que sólo se almacena el número total de comparticiones por tipo para una comunidad/publicación, sin ninguna noción de fecha. Así que tengo que hacer una tarea en un ETL que pueda hacer esto cada noche (el ETL sólo se ejecuta por la noche).

```
from etl.utils.logging import info
from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name
from etl.mysql.operations import add_column_if_not_exists, add_index_if_not_exists

def get_shares():
    # Je crée une table avec pour chaque jour le nombre de partages par type de partage.
    with db as c:

        # Il faut créer la table shares
        info("Creating table and populating `shares` ...")
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE shares IF NOT EXISTS
                                Date AS DATE, Shares AS INTEGER;""")

        # Si c'est la première ligne de la base de données on met le nombre de partage total
        c.execute("""
        INSERT INTO
        shares (`Date`, `Shares`)
        SELECT
          CURDATE() as date,
          SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_messenger) + SUM(shares_pinterest) + SUM(shares_twitter) + SUM(shares_whatsapp) AS total
          FROM communities
        """)

        # sinon on rajoute une ligne avec la somme des shares moins le résultat de la dernière ligne
        c.execute("""
        SELECT CURDATE(), (
            SUM(`shares_copylink`+ `shares_email`+ `shares_facebook`+ `shares_messenger`+ `shares_pinterest`+ `shares_twitter`+ `shares_whatsapp`)
            - SELECT sharesnb FROM shares WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM shares)
        FROM communities
        """)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Y deshacerse de las dos primeras solicitudes SQL una vez que estoy seguro de que ha funcionado al menos una vez.

Tendré problemas con:

```
SELECT CURDATE(), (
                SUM(`shares_copylink`+ `shares_email`+ `shares_facebook`+ `shares_messenger`+ `shares_pinterest`+ `shares_twitter`+ `shares_whatsapp`)
                - SELECT sharesnb FROM shares WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM shares)
            FROM communities
```

Hasta qué no hay `id` en `shares`

Sino, ¿Cómo se empieza a calcular el número de eventos diarios a partir de una tabla que sólo almacena el número total de eventos?